# UILabel alignment

Tags: iphone

In my app I need to show a large volume of data(news) to the user. I tried using UIWebView to show up the news data. It worked fine but the performance was low. UIWebView takes time to show up all the data.
So I started using UILabel to show up the data. This worked fine with no performance issue. But the problem is when ever a line ends the UIWebView automatically puts spaces in between to align the text properly. But UILabel is not doing the same. So the text is not aligned properly. how do we get the text aligned properly as it is done in UIWebView

Thanks In Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this is to build your own text layout using UIKit's NSString's extentions: drawAtPoint:InFont as recommended in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924757/cant-display-selected-text-with-different-colors-in-uitextview-what-should-i-do/955065#955065).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UITextView.  This should wrap text a little nicer than the UILabel.

Comment: I tried using UITextView, but I don't find any difference. Still my problem persists.